# Create a One-to-Many Spatial View with ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, enterprise-geodatabase

We have two datasets: parcels and owners.  This is a many-to-many relationship, where a parcel can have multiple owners and there may be multiple properties on a single parcel (also with multiple owners: condos or strata property)

We would like to publish this data to ArcGIS Server, and issue queries on it, so that we can get a single result for a single condo owner.  Currently, when mapping the condo owners back to the parcel, we get all other condo owners, which gets confusing if the result was obtained by a text search.

In ArcGIS 10 and earlier, it's possible to create a spatial view that generates a unique Object ID field for repeated geometries.  This lets us publish a parcels layer with stacked parcels for owners.

Is this possible with ArcGIS 10.1?  The [online documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002q000000r3000000) implies that ObjectID and Geometry must be obtained from the same feature class in a spatial view.

The underlying database is SQL Server.  We do not want to convert the data storage type.

Answer (score 1):

This problem often comes up when doing animations. I suggest trying either the Make Query Layer or Make Query Table tools.

Comment: When I made a view directly in the database, ArcMap wants to add that as a query layer.  However, when I publish a query layer, my ObjectID field isn't recognized as an OID field, it's just a number.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a spatial view using the old way (SDE command) then use an ID field (parcel number) and the shape column from your parcel layer. Then use SQL ssms to finish the join that will give you multiple polygons when you have multiple owners-----if you really need a join. It really sounds like setting up a relate would be better and relates will publish as well.

The join is best if you need symbology based on ownership info.